# Unable to add to keychain iOS

Tags: ios, keychain

I have been trying to add keys to the keychain in **iOS 8**. I have tried the example: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3 and using various libraries including: [JNKeychain](https://github.com/jeremangnr/JNKeychain). With JNKeychain, the following code produces a null result:

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
    [JNKeychain saveValue:@"test@example.net" forKey:(__bridge NSString*)(kSecAttrAccount)];
    NSData *data = [JNKeychain loadValueForKey:(__bridge NSString*)(kSecAttrAccount)];
    NSString *email = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Email: %@", email);
}
```

I was expecting that this code would return "Email: test@example.net". Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `iOS8` `SecItemAdd` and `SecItemCopyMatching` returns error code `-34018`(entitlements not found) .To solve this problem you have to turn on the **“Keychain Sharing” in Capabilities tab.**

Go to Target -> Capabilities -> turn on the “Keychain Sharing”

than clean, build and run again.